# How to use setItems and choose a number and call it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1.
I want to create an `AlertDialog` with two(doesn't really matter how many) phone numbers to select and you can choose one and it will make a call to that number.
So far I came with this but it crashed when I choose a number:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_manu , menu);
    return true ;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

           case R.id.Call :

            AlertDialog.Builder menuDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SeconedScreen.this) ;
            menuDialog.setTitle("chose a number to call") ;
            menuDialog.setItems(phonenumbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int phonenumbers) {

                    switch (phonenumbers){
                        case 0  :
                            Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL) ;
                            dial.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(phonenumbers))) ;
                            startActivity(dial);
                            break ;
                    }
                }
            }) ;
            menuDialog.show() ;
            return true ;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the string value was wrong its suppose to be String.valueOf("tel: 0548978978")
well i manged to get it working by doing this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.map :
            Intent openmap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) ;
            openmap.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.maps.com"));
            startActivity(openmap);
            return true ;

        case R.id.Call :

            final AlertDialog.Builder menuDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SeconedScreen.this) ;
            menuDialog.setTitle("chose a number to call") ;
            menuDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(phonenumbers,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int phonenumbers) {

                    switch (phonenumbers){
                        case 0  :

                            Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL) ;
                            dial.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf("tel: 0548978978"))) ;
                            startActivity(dial);
                            break ;

                        case 1 :
                            Intent dial1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL) ;
                            dial1.setData(Uri.parse(String.valueOf("tel: 0586587989"))) ;
                            startActivity(dial1);
                            break ;
                    }

                }

            }) ;
            menuDialog.show() ;
            return true ;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}